# Java - Generics with lists

Tags: java, generics

I wrote a function for my cache to retrieve a specific object. This way I don't need to cast it .

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T inCache(Class<T> obj, String token) {

        Object cacheObj = Cache.get(token);
        if (cacheObj != null) {

            if (obj.isAssignableFrom(cacheObj.getClass())) {
                return (T) cacheObj;
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

I am using it like this

```
String s = inCache(String.class, title);
```

But now I have a list of Strings in my cache and I can't use it like this

```
List<String> ipList = Util.inCache(List<String>.class, title);
```

The problem is the `List<String>.class` . I am very new to java, how do I have to write it?

Comment: as a side note, you don't need that suppresswarnings, use `return obj.cast(cacheObj)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get class of `List<String>`, in your case the only way is:

```
List<String> ipList = (List<String>)Util.inCache(List.class, title);
```

Comment: with an unavoidable SuppressWarnings.

Answer (score 6):

There is a concept in java called type erasure.  Due to legacy reasons, something like List is just a list.  It doesn't remember that it is a list of string at run time.  You should just write List.class.

You can then specify the type of object in the List when iterating through it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
List<String> ipList = Util.inCache(List.class, title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
List<String> inList = (List<String>)Test.inCache(List.class, title);
```

And you can do also -

```
List<String> inList = Test.inCache((Class<? extends List<String>>)List.class, token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify Joe's answer ( I don't have enough reputation to comment), at runtime there is no difference between a `List <String>` and `List<Integer>` or any other type of `List`, generics aren't kept at runtime.

Meaning, `List<String>.class` is completely identical to `List<Integer>.class` and is actually `List.class`. This is a weakness of the Java type system. I'm not familiar with a simple way to implement what you wish for.

A code proof for the heck of it :

```
// It is true that      
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();                                               
    System.out.println( stringList.getClass() == integerList.getClass()  );

    // And that ... 
    List objectList = new ArrayList();
    System.out.println( stringList.getClass() == objectList.getClass()  );

    //However, the following is false because a different implementation is used ( I wanted a false case)
    List objectLinkedList = new LinkedList();
    System.out.println(  objectLinkedList.getClass() == objectList.getClass() );
```